# Was Rose selfish or unhinged?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

It struck me as odd that Rose

> prevented Finn from finishing his run at the battering ram cannon.

She seemed to be putting her self interest ahead of any desire to preserve or help the Resistance. In fact, if it weren’t for what happened later, her actions could have

> spelled the end of the Resistance, as that seemed to be their only shot at avoiding destruction.

The reason I wonder if she may even have been unhinged is that the way she

> stopped him could just as easily have smeared him all over the salt flats as save him, and indeed she plum near killed herself in the process. She wasn’t some ace pilot, but a mechanic. Even her explanation before passing out sounded like she was channeling Don Quixote a bit.

Did she do the noble thing?

Is it really altruistic to risk her life and

> Finn’s and sacrifice everyone left in the Resistance

just so she could

> save Finn

?

Comment: I completely agree - she was selfish and IMO should not have interfered

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no reason to think Finn's attempt would have succeeded.  Given the plot context, it is far more likely that it would have been futile.

Comment: Finn seemed to think it would work or he wouldn’t have tried

Comment: @jinglesthula, Finn was desperate and not thinking clearly.  Poe knew it wasn't going to work, that's why he ordered the retreat.

Comment: Poe may have also retreated simply because of being burned when taking the opposite course with the dreadnaught. It seems like if it’s the only hope - if it’s that or be trapped - it’s worth it even if the odds are very slim. Though all characters could easily have been affected by the fog of war

Comment: Her story line was a complete waste for the film. When she wrecked Finn, I figured he would run over and say "Why did you do that!!" This Star Wars film had a lot of sub plots that were silly and not needed.

Answer (score 17):

## She believed that the key to winning the war was saving the people they love instead of attacking the people they hate.

Your question was asked by Finn himself, immediately after Rose ended his suicide run and saved him.

Her response was:

> **That's how we'll win: not by fighting what we hate, but by saving what we love.**

(Source: Memory, after seeing the film last night.)

Whether that's selfish or unhinged is a matter of opinion, but at the very least it *does not* appear to be an act of selfishness on her part.  She truly believes she is acting in the best interests of the Resistance.

It's worth noting that she lost her sister at the beginning of the film in the bombing run on the Dreadnought.  As a result, she is in a somewhat fragile state that could certainly influence her thoughts and decisions.

Comment: Quote is dead on, saw it a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Ah, right - I forgot she says she feels it’s the key to winning. Unhinged? Perhaps. She is likely in full PTSD mode at the time. But she at least doesn’t give as explanation “BECAUSE I LOVE YOU!!!!”

Comment: As a literary device, Rose's action and quote give a nice black & white contrast with Kylo's actions a few minutes later of firing every gun he has on one man. Since Star Wars has always been about the morality of good vs evil, there's a nice out-of-universe explanation for why Rose's action needs to be there as a central theme of the story.

Comment: "Unhinged" would be *demonstrated* by belief in silly justifications, not by acting without any reasons at all.

Comment: I'd argue that Finn was doing it for the ones he loved, even though it was killing those he hated. He wanted to save the others in the resistance that he loved. So in this respect it makes Rose seem selfish to me

Answer (score 3):

I'll change my answer. I actually have made up my mind.

Rose was neither selfish nor unhinged, she took a rational decision out of her situation.

After also seeing Wisecrack's revive of the themes of this movie i came to compare Finn's sacrifice to the other sacrifices which were made during the movie.

Rose must have realized that Finn's sacrifice was unlikely to be successful. For her it must have been like seeing Finn trying to rescue the rebels but realizing that if it won't work, which is much likely, she will loose Finn in vain. With no effect whatsoever. Would you let a friend run into a rolling train because you are stuck on the tracks ? I think if you could you would stop that friend.

Rose lost her sister in the first sacrifice in the movie. Right at the beginning when Poe's greed leads to a hot-headed attack on the star destroyer. Which, let's not forget, succeeds by pure luck. While nobody actually knows about the very very lucky remote catch inside the last bomber. But what everyone probably knows is that the last bomber was shot and exploding (iirc) while dropping the bombs. The attack was to 99% successful stopped by the counter attacking TIE-Fighters.

Rose following the rebellion's heroes and the stories about them must at least have known that the losses in this attack were severe ad probably realized that the result could much likely have been in vain.

Considering this in the last sacrifice: Finn's attempt to destroy the cannon it was just a logic conclusion for Rose. Poe, the guy who led the other attack on the star destroyer turns around and calls off the counter attack. Which must spark some doubt in her. In this situation Rose has enough influence to stop another dear person from disappearing from her live, much likely in vain. For her she slim chance that he might rescue everyone has far less weight than keeping someone she loves alive. Even from a non-emotional perspective, it was the most likely successful thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

@Praxis's quote is correct, but I'd like to add that from a storytelling perspective is it made abundantly clear that Finn's attack is futile.   Not only is his ship trivial compared to the supergun, but it is clearly shown that his guns are completely melted away by the energy weapon before Rose rams him.   This removes the question of whether Rose is selfish from the table because it is clear she did not undo any outcome that would have been helpful had she not saved Finn.

Answer (score -1):

**She was selfish**
She told Finn,

> That's how we'll win this war: by saving the people we love instead of killing ?the people we hate.

which does make her sound like she is acting out of altruism, but looking at the circumstances around the action you see that she was saving him because she didn't want to lose another person she cared about. It had nothing to do with winning the war, she was willing to sacrifice the whole resistance for him to not die right there.

Comment: Is it not possible that she was indeed right, and saving the people they love is the way to winning the war?

Comment: @Edlothiad, that is possible, and could still fall under "selfish" rather than "unhinged" which were the only two option OP provided.

Comment: With the information they had, there was no way of knowing that that act wouldn’t doom the resistance. They went out on the run with the knowledge that if they couldn’t take out the cannon, the whole resistance would die. I don’t have any doubt that Rian Johnson believed she was right, considering that it was a part of Poe’s character arc, but in universe that was a selfish move.